# convert colnames() into a new row

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset as below and I want to create a new row that contains the values of `colnames(df)`. Many thanks in advance.

```
df <- head(mtcars); df
```

Expected Answer

```
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
newRow            mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Note that you can't mix data types in a data frame and retain the mixed types.  Adding a character row will convert all numeric rows to character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rbind` is what you need:

```
rbind(newRow = colnames(df), df)
```

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
newRow             mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21   6  160 110  3.9  2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85  2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15  3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76  3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: The same with the `iris` dataset does not work appropriate. Throws `NA` `rbind(newRow = colnames(iris), iris)`

Comment: @TarJae you get `NA` for `Species` column, right? It makes sense because `Species` is `factor`. If you want this code to work, you need to make sure that `Species` column is `character`.