# convert column names into a new row

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549206/convert-colnames-into-a-new-row?noredirect=1#comment119395205_67549206) as below which works perfectly fine with `mtcars` but I was wondering if there is a better solution than converting `Species` column into character. Many thanks in advance

```
df <- head(iris); df
rbind(newRow = colnames(df), df) 

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: What about the other columns?  it also converts to character

Comment: I agree with @akrun. In general, I would not try to "mix" `characters` with `numeric` variables unless extremely necessary. Because it makes everything `character`. @SeymaKalay why do you want to keep everything as `character` and leave the `Species` column as `factor`?

Comment: This was a suggestion in the code link but I am looking for a more efficient way, if there is any.

Comment: How does this differ from the question you already posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(as.list(names(df)), df))
```